# Xamarin iOS - Archive for Publishing: Could not resolve reference Mono.Android

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I've been developing a Xamarin app for both Android and iOS, and after publishing to Google Play now would like to launch on the Apple App Store as well. I have installed Visual Studio 2019 on a Mac, and can successfully test a release version of the app on a simulated device. Now, following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/app-distribution/app-store-distribution/publishing-to-the-app-store?tabs=macos) guide on publishing to the App Store I need to create an archive for publishing. However, when doing so I get the lovely error:

Could not resolve reference. Could not locate the assembly "Mono.Android". Check to make sure the assembly exists on dirk. If this reference is required by your code you may get compilation errors.

I never reference Mono.Android directly in my code, and there are also no compilation errors when building and executing the Xamarin.iOS project. There are also several versions of the Mono.Android.dll on disk, located at /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Android.framework/Versions/11.0.2.0/lib/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/[version]/Mono.Android.dll

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Check the projects **references**, there is an Android reference there.

Comment: The Xamarin.iOS project only references the project's shared code, System, System.Core, System.XML, and Xamain.iOS. Besides that, the shared code has a few dependencies: Netstandard.Library, Xamarin.Forms, Xamarin.Essentials, and Newtonsoft.JSON. No Android references though

Comment: The Xamarin.Android project does of course reference Mono.Android, but is it unloaded on the Mac.

Comment: Can you please have a try with re-reference the MonoAndroid.dll as mentioned in [this thread](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/91123/mono-android-could-not-be-found).